# Spring Security disregard my basic auth unless I specify access role

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, resteasy

Using Spring 3.1.2 and RestEasy 2.3.4.

I've got some REST resources. However, I don't want to specify in Spring what roles are needed for all of them. This is my current setup:

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:http-basic/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/secrets/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**"/>
</security:http>
```

Calls to '/secret/**' gets authenticated and I can access the user and roles from the SecurityContextHolder-object. Calls to '/**' however don't get authenticated even though I pass basic credentials. I want to authorise based on data being fetched and not by urls.

It seem that Spring Security disregard my basic auth unless I specify access

Comment: Consider change the title of your question. It's not clear what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with a less than perfect solution. I put the secrets url on top with authenticated access. Then I allowed all other unauthenticated access to GET methods. This solves the issue for now. I still would rather like to have authentication based on the data being accessed.

The intercept-url line in the middle here which do require authentication will not ever convey authentication information, even if it should exist, to the service.

```
<security:http use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/secrets/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" method="GET" access="isAnonymous()"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
    <security:http-basic/>
</security:http>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try **isFullyAuthenticated()** expression:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isFullyAuthenticated()" />
```

Comment: That is just the same as authenticated without 'remember me'. What I want is the basic authentication; if it has been given. I don't care that much for url-based authorisation. I need to check if the user have access to this data item.

Comment: If you have a complex case then consider Spring Security [ACL](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#domain-acls) fetaure. If you have a simple case then you can emulate ACL via custom web security expression